# text() not showing/rendered on iOS jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Currently, I am making scanning function in my website.
 And there is different time between last scan time and current time.
My script work normally in desktop browser and android browser, but it not showing same in iOS

Here is my code.

Example output in desktop and android devices

> 1 Hr 2 mins 1 sec ago

[image: desktop]

Example output in iOS ( chrome, Firefox and safari give same output )

> ago

[image: iOS]

Only ago text show in iOS.
 anyone know what's wrong with my code?

```js
d = 74;
var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hr" : " hrs") + (m > 0 || s > 0 ? ", " : "") : "";
var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " min" : " mins") + (s > 0 ? ", " : "") : "";
var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " sec" : " secs") : "";

differentTime = "last scan " + hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay + " ago "

console.log(differentTime)
$("#last-scan").text(differentTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="last-scan" class='last-scan-text'> </span><span>by Scanner_19022 </span>
```

Comment: do you get "Ago" or "ago" ?

Comment: edited. auto-capitalize sorry